# Error in a Hello World CodenameOne Java program

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to run a simple Hello World program with CodenameOne in Java.  I'm trying to add a button to the app.  I get two compiler errors, both of them:

java: cannot find symbol

symbol: class Button

Here is the code:

```
//ORIGIONAL CODE
package CodenameOneHelloWorld;


import static com.codename1.ui.CN.*;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.io.NetworkEvent;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class MyApplication {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    public void init(Object context) {
        // use two network threads instead of one
        updateNetworkThreadCount(2);

        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature
        Log.bindCrashProtection(true);

        addNetworkErrorListener(err -> {
            // prevent the event from propagating
            err.consume();
            if(err.getError() != null) {
                Log.e(err.getError());
            }
            Log.sendLogAsync();
            Dialog.show("Connection Error", "There was a networking error in the connection to " + err.getConnectionRequest().getUrl(), "OK", null);
        });        
    }
    
    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
        hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
        Button b = new Button("Show Dialog"); // LINE HAND-TYPED ACCORDING TO TUTORIAL
        hi.add(b); // LINE HAND-TYPED ACCORDING TO TUTORIAL
        b.addActionListener((e) -> Dialog.show("Dialog Title", "Hi", "OK", null)); // LINE HAND-TYPED ACCORDING TO TUTORIAL
        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = getCurrentForm();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = getCurrentForm();
        }
    }
    
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

After following the compiler's directions, I have the new following code:

```
// CODE MODIFIED BY SUGGESTION FROM COMPILER
package CodenameOneHelloWorld;


import static com.codename1.ui.CN.*;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;

import java.awt.*;  // ADDED IMPORT LINE
import java.io.IOException;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.io.NetworkEvent;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose 
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class MyApplication {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    public void init(Object context) {
        // use two network threads instead of one
        updateNetworkThreadCount(2);

        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature
        Log.bindCrashProtection(true);

        addNetworkErrorListener(err -> {
            // prevent the event from propagating
            err.consume();
            if(err.getError() != null) {
                Log.e(err.getError());
            }
            Log.sendLogAsync();
            Dialog.show("Connection Error", "There was a networking error in the connection to " + err.getConnectionRequest().getUrl(), "OK", null);
        });        
    }
    
    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
        hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
        Button b = new Button("Show Dialog");
        hi.add(String.valueOf(b)); // CHANGED LINE AS SUGGESTED BY COMPILER
        b.addActionListener((e) -> Dialog.show("Dialog Title", "Hi", "OK", null));
        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = getCurrentForm();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = getCurrentForm();
        }
    }
    
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

The new code compiles clean, but when run in the simulator, the app displays an error message instead of the button.

Does anybody have any idea on how to get the button to display properly in the Hello World app?

Answer (score 0):

AWT won't work here. The IDE offers more than one option when you try to import and the other option should be `import com.codename1.ui.Button;`. You can see the full list of supported classes in the JavaDocs here: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/